# Dataframe append dataframe to excel with sheet names?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I desire to append multiple dataframes to a blank dataframe, and then export them to excel file with sheet name. I am stuck with it now. I simplify my code and look like this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def calculate_file():
    sheet_df = pd.DataFrame()
    for i in range(40):
#This is a toy dataframe
        random_data = np.random.randint(10,25,size=(5,3))
        df = pd.DataFrame(random_data, columns=['Column_1','Column_2','Column_3'])
    sheet_df = sheet_df.append(df)
    return(sheet_df)
calculate_file()
```

My desire output is dataframe with 40 sheet names exporting to an Excel file, and the name is Sheet1 to Sheet 40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the sheet name somewhere, for instance in the index:

```
def calculate_file():
    sheet_df = pd.DataFrame()
    for i in range(1, 41):
        random_data = np.random.randint(10, 25, size=(5,3))
        df = pd.DataFrame(random_data,
                          columns=['Column_1', 'Column_2', 'Column_3'],
                          index=[f'Sheet {i}'] * len(random_data))
        sheet_df = pd.concat([sheet_df, df])
    return(sheet_df)

sheet_df = calculate_file()
```

Then you can use an [`ExcelWriter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html):

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:
    for sheet in sheet_df.index.unique():
        sheet_df.loc[sheet].to_excel(writer, sheet, index=False)
```

[image]

Comment: I appreciate it sooooo much. Thanks for helping me, or I need to export the data one by one :)